# Is there a way to find the indices of common (exactly the same) elements in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, group-by

Given a dataframe such as,

```
num <- c(5,10,15,20,25)
letter <- c("A", "B", "A", "C", "B")
thelist <- data.frame(num, letter)
```

I need to find the indices where the letters are the same.
Output:

```
A 1 3 
B 2 5
C 4
```

Then, take these indices and find the mean of those indices in num. 
Output:

```
A 10
B 17.5
C 20
```

I cannot use loops or `if` statements, I am looking at using a sort of `apply`, `which`, etc.

Comment: consider to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) one of the answers if they made you happy and solved your problem.

Answer (score 5):

As the objective is to find the `mean` for each similar 'letter', it is better to group by 'letter' and get the `mean` of 'num'

```
library(dplyr)
thelist %>% 
   group_by(letter) %>% 
   summarise(num = mean(num))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  letter   num
#  <fct>  <dbl>
#1 A       10  
#2 B       17.5
#3 C       20
```

---

or in `base R`

```
aggregate(num ~ letter, thelist, mean)
```

---

To find the index of the same 'letter', we can `split` the sequence of rows by 'letter

```
split(seq_len(nrow(thelist)), thelist$letter)
#$A
#[1] 1 3

#$B
#[1] 2 5

#$C
#[1] 4
```

Comment: Isn't the problem of finding the indices a XY problem? (Upvote, BTW).

Comment: @RuiBarradas  Sure, it is a XY problem.

Answer (score 4):

Another option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(thelist)[, .(ind = paste(.I, collapse = " "),
                   mean_num = mean(num)
                   ), 
               by = letter]
```

Output:

```
   letter ind mean_num
1:      A 1 3     10.0
2:      B 2 5     17.5
3:      C   4     20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `dplyr`/tidyverse for this:

```
# setup
library(tidyverse)
# group by letters then get mean of num
thelist %>% 
  group_by(letter) %>% 
  summarise(mean_num = mean(num))
```

You could also use base R with a for loop:

```
lets <- unique(thelist$letter)
x <- rep(NA, length(lets))
for(i in 1:3){
  x[i] <- mean(thelist$num[thelist$letter %in% lets[i]])
}
x
```